# How to change Callout leader size in Plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Take this example:

```
Plot[Callout[Sin[x], Sin[x], Above], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question:** How can I change the length of the line connecting the $\sin(x)$ label with the plotted curve?

I believe this line is called the "leader" and it can be modified with the [`LeaderSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeaderSize.html) option. But adding either `LeaderSize -> 10` or `LeaderSize -> {10}` to `Callout` makes no difference.

**Motivation:** When the plot has a wide aspect ratio, the leaders tend to be too long. I assume this is because they are computed relative to the figure width.

```
Plot[Callout[Sin[x], Sin[x], Above], {x, 0, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: i don't know why  but it seems that  the both the leader and the neck  change only if you set the position to Automatic : 
Plot[Callout[Sin[x], Sin[x], Automatic, 
  LeaderSize -> {{70, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}], {x, 0, Pi}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/4]

Answer (score 2):

maybe help:

```
Table[Plot[
  Callout[Sin[x], Sin[x], Above, 
   LeaderSize -> {100, 90 \[Degree], i}], {x, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> Full], {i, 0, 30, 5}]
```

[image]

or

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Callout[Sin[x], "Sin[x]", {Pi/2, a}, Pi/2], {x, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2}}], {a, 1.1, 1.75}]
```

Comment: Please add a plot demonstrating the effect of your code.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I have re-edited the answer

Comment: Somehow I was hoping for an answer where the label did go further away from the curve, instead of the gap doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround (besides the obvious one of specifying an explicit coordinate instead of [`Above`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Above)) where I shrink the neck size:

```
Plot[
    Callout[
        Sin[x],
        Rotate[Sin[x], -Pi/2],
        Above,
        FrameMargins -> 0,
        LeaderSize -> {Automatic, {0, Pi/2}}
    ],
    {x, 0, Pi},
    AspectRatio -> 1/4
]
```

[image]

Another possibility is to bend the callout:

```
Plot[
    Callout[
        Sin[x],
        Sin[x],
        Above,
        LeaderSize -> {Automatic, {0, Pi/4}}
    ],
    {x, 0, Pi},
    AspectRatio -> 1/4
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider specifying position for the callout {pos, epos}

[image]

```
Plot[Callout[Sin[x], "Sin(x)", {N@\[Pi]/2, 2.}, 
CalloutMarker -> "\[EmptyCircle]", CalloutStyle -> Gray], {x, 0, 
Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Here you are explicitly specifying the callout position.  `LeaderSize` has no effect  Can you point this out in the answer, and remove the superfluous `LeaderSize` option (since it does nothing here)?

Answer (score 1):

Using different neck lengths:

```
 Plot[Callout[Sin[x], Rotate[Sin[x],- 90 Degree], Above, 
   LeaderSize -> {{100, 90 Degree, 0}, {#, 90 Degree}}], {x, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, ImagePadding->50, ImageSize-> 300] &/@ {0, 30, 70}// Row
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, once the position of the callout label is set (e.g. with `Above`), the length of the leader is ignored. Instead, one has to let the position of the label be calculated automatically (i.e. `Automatic`) and specify the position of the anchor instead:

```
Plot[
  Callout[
    Sin[x], Sin[x], Automatic, Scaled[0.3], 
    LeaderSize -> {{15, 90 Degree, 3}, {10, 180 Degree}}
  ],
  {x, 0, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 0.2
]
```

Unfortunately, symbolic positions such as `Above` are not available for the callout anchor position, so an explicit position is needed; `Scaled` coordinates work best for me here.

I ran into similar trouble recently, which is what led me to your question. The solution I propose above is discussed in more detail here: [LeaderSize has no effect on Callout in Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/292601/27951).