# LeaderSize has no effect on Callout in Plot

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I was trying to change the position and distance from the plot of a label generated using `Callout`. The following code specifies different `LeaderSize` for the Callout, but there is no difference in the resulting plots:

```
Row[
  Plot[
    Callout[Sin[x], "sin(x)", Scaled[1/4], LeaderSize -> #],
    {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Small
  ] & /@ {5, 15, 50}
]
```

[image: three plots with the identical labels and no difference in callout leader size]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest previous question I found is [How to change Callout leader size in Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154985/27951) but the answers did not contain what I think may be the key issue. It took me a while to figure out what I was doing wrong and I got pretty frustrated in the process, so I thought I'd share the solution I found here.

The `Callout` syntax: `Callout[data, expr, pos, apos]` specifies that the callout *label* `expr`  is to be located at position `pos`, and the callout *anchor* (i.e. the point on the plot where the callout leader "starts") at position `apos`.

I had thought that, if I specify a position `pos` for the *label*, and a size or other properties of the leader with `LeaderSize`, then the position of the callout *anchor* would be adjusted automatically. However, **this is not true**. If the position of the label is specified, then most specifications in `LeaderSize` are quietly ignored, as shown above in the question. This was very counter-intuitive to me. [To be fair, not all `LeaderSize` settings are ignored: some angles and distances from the plot are respected, but the length of the leader itself is not.]

It turns out that, to change the size of the callout leader, the callout label itself needs to be free to move around, so it should be set to `Automatic`. The position of the *label anchor* should be set instead. The system then adjusts the position of the label to comply with the properties requested with `LeaderSize`.

In short, I needed: `Callout[data, label, Automatic, position]`, as in the following amended code:

```
Row[
  Plot[
    Callout[Sin[x], "sin(x)", Automatic, Scaled[1/4], LeaderSize -> #],
    {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Small
  ] & /@ {5, 15, 50}
]
```

[image: callout leaders are now of different lengths in the three plots]